# Link to Internet Explorer automatic Update

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer

I'm creating a blog where wysywig html editor is used for comments, but it needs IE >= 10.

So I would like create a link on this blog which can start an Internet Explorer Update to make it easy for people having a version lower than IE 10.

Is it possible? And if yes, how can it be done or implemented on it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it's not possible.** The reason for this is that an "Internet Explorer Update" is a job of the operating system. Any actions that are being controlled by the operating system, such as launching programs and applications or downloading/creating/editing/deleting files on the file system, running updates, etc. are not allowed to be executed via the browser.

Could you imagine what would happen if we had control over one of these through the browser? Chaos and no security overall.

**UPDATE:** Alternatively, you can check the browser version and if it is IE 10 or older, you can show a pop-up with a message, where you can include a link to download the latest version of Internet Explorer.
Here is the code which sets a variable, which can be used later. It tells if the browser is <= 10 `var ie10OrOlder = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ");`

Comment: Thanks Cvetomir,
so how can i invit the user to update his browser (ie < 10)?

Comment: Thanks for this code.
But users of this blog have an informatic very low level.
I think they don't know if they have an 32 or 64 bits ...
So the link to the lastest version of Internet Explorer ask it.

I will test it but i think they'll don't like it.

Comment: @La Buse Sadly, you don't have another option. Alternatively, you can send them to a page with instructions on how to update their browser.